# TensorBoard hangs when visualizing an Object Detection graph

Tags: google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

I need to visualize the structure of a TensorFlow Object Detection model.  I am trying to use TensorBoard in Colab with the code below. When TensorBoard loads the logs, it gets stuck on the step "Namespace hierarchy: Finding similar subgraphs".

```
!pip install -U tensorflow

import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.python.client import session  
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops  
from tensorflow.python.tools import saved_model_utils
from tensorflow.python.framework import importer
from tensorflow.python.summary import summary

!wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz
!tar -xf ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz

%load_ext tensorboard

log_dir = '/content/logs'
tag_set = "serve"
model_dir = '/content/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/saved_model'

with session.Session(graph=ops.Graph()) as sess:
  input_graph_def = saved_model_utils.get_meta_graph_def(model_dir,
                                                        tag_set).graph_def
  importer.import_graph_def(input_graph_def)

  pb_visual_writer = summary.FileWriter(log_dir)
  pb_visual_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
  print("Model Imported. Visualize by running: "
        "tensorboard --logdir={}".format(log_dir))

%tensorboard --logdir=$log_dir
```

Here is a link to the notebook:  https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MrbNJYR2ds8RRgIBvgUgAILw0Jwdygui?usp=sharing.

Environment:
Browser:  Chrome
OS:  Windows
RAM:  8 GB

Eventually, I start getting the errors below.

FYI, I tried to run this same process on a Windows computer with 4 GB of RAM, with a TensorBoard server running in a shell.  I accessed TensorBoard using the default URL (outside of a notebook).  It failed at the same point in the startup process.

I see that [Tensorboard got stuck in 'namespace hierarchy finding similar subgraphs'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62234889/tensorboard-got-stuck-in-namespace-hierarchy-finding-similar-subgraphs) and [I'm struggling to implement tensorboard monitoring into the Mask_RCNN training process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61646882/im-struggling-to-implement-tensorboard-monitoring-into-the-mask-rcnn-training-p) asked similar questions, but no answer has been provided.

Thanks in advance -- this would really help in the important project I am doing for my company.

[image]

[image: Pages Unresponsive]

[image: Could not load JavaScript]

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 issues that I believe I now know how to fix.

1. Insufficient RAM/CPU -> run on a computer with more resources
2. Complex graph, needs to be enlarged -> Use Zoom to see nodes
3. Variables not initialized -> Evaluate model to show edges of graph

#### 1.  Insufficient RAM/CPU

Running the process on a Windows computer with 24 GB RAM and 8 i7 cores eliminated the crashes for me. Sometimes I get a message about the page becoming unresponsive, but you can just click the "Wait" button and it will load.  The load itself was also much faster.

#### 2.  Complex graph, needs to be enlarged

Running the above code, TensorBoard displays what appears to be a blank screen.  However, there is a faint outline of graph nodes.

[image: Initial view of graph]

Zoom in to see the details.  The navigation box in the lower right portion of the screen is helpful.

[image: Zooming in]

#### 3.  Initialize variables

Instead of the code in my question above, use the following:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

!pip install -U tensorflow

%load_ext tensorboard

# Download model
!wget http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/tf2/20200711/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz
!tar -xf ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8.tar.gz

model_dir = '/content/ssd_resnet50_v1_fpn_640x640_coco17_tpu-8/saved_model'
log_dir = '/content/logs'

if os.path.exists(log_dir):
  ! rm -r $log_dir

@tf.function
def f(x):
    imported = tf.saved_model.load(model_dir)
    results = imported(x)
    return results
    
#Initialize variables
imgs = np.zeros((1,640,640,3),dtype=int)
imgs_t = tf.constant(imgs, dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8)
imported_g = f.get_concrete_function(imgs_t).graph

# Export the graph
with session.Session(graph=imported_g) as sess:
  pb_visual_writer = summary.FileWriter(log_dir)
  pb_visual_writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
  print("Model Imported. Visualize by running: "
        "tensorboard --logdir={}".format(log_dir))
```

The new graph shows the edges of the graph, not just the nodes.

Here's a notebook that you can run:  https://colab.research.google.com/gist/mherzog01/d631998cb4d0b0dbcb70492b933a67c8/tensorboard-hangs-during-graph-visualization-solution.ipynb.